# how to display the dynamic value in html text area

Tags: javascript, html

I have a requirement like this:

```
<div class="card-header">Data</div>
  <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" disabled>
             <label class="custom-control-label ">Greater Than
          </label>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" disabled>
             <label class="custom-control-label ">Lesser Than
          </label>
         </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

if the user selects Greater than I need to display like this in the text-area in the same page like this:

```
    { 
      'Greater Than':"Yes",
      'Lesser Than' : "No" 
     }
```

Comment: i can't see a textarea element in your example and also can't see what u tried so far, to make it working

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
document.getElementById("greater-than-checkbox").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
document.getElementById("lesser-than-checkbox").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  const greaterThanCheckbox = document.getElementById('greater-than-checkbox');
  const lesserThanCheckbox = document.getElementById('lesser-than-checkbox');
  const textareaResult = document.getElementById('textarea-result');

  let greaterThan = greaterThanCheckbox.checked
  let lesserThan = lesserThanCheckbox.checked

  textareaResult.value = JSON.stringify({ 
        'Greater Than': greaterThan,
        'Lesser Than' : lesserThan 
  })
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mtfLrkz8/10